# jQuery Validation .after()

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to be able to add an asterick to the end of a text box during $("form").validate. I can do this with   $(element).after("*"); but how can I gracefully remove this if the keyed in text or entry is correct. jQuery dosent have a   $(element).remove("*"); Any help with this would be awesome.

Comment: wrap in a <span class="required"> and then remove that element when the field is valid.

Comment: Add the * within a span and give it a classname or id. Then on the Keyup event of the textbox you can check if the value is correct and then hide or remove the span..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting it in an element which you then remove:

```js
$(element).after('<span id="remove_me">*</span>');
```

and use this to remove it

```js
$('#remove_me').remove();
```

you can also have the element already present yet hidden with css `display:none;` and then use `.show()` to display it when the validate form needs it and `.hide()` to remove it.

Comment: this seemed to be the best option for me, the only thing I did a lil' different was give the span a friendlier id: `$(element).after("<span id=" + "sp_"+$(element).attr("id") + ">*</span>");` and to remove it, I can use `$("sp_" + $(element).attr("id")).remove();` thanks all for help with this.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<input type="text" /><span id="error">*</span>
```

**css**

```
#error { display:none; }
```

**js**

```
if( valid ) ? $('#error').hide() : $('#error').show();
```

Like the comments said, you can check this validation via any `js` event; the most popular probably being `keyup` or on the form `submit`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example, you'd have to insert the adding and removing in your validation where needed:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dReqD/)

```
$('.required').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().remove();
}).after('<span>*</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
    $('.error').remove();
    $('#txt1').after('<span class="error">*</span> ');
    hideError();
});

$('#txt1').on('change', function() {
    hideError();
});

function hideError() {
    if ($('#txt1').val() == 'hello') {
        $('.error').hide();
    }

}
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cwAEA/1/) for working example..​